# mixing in modules that depend on each other?

Tags: ruby

Module `A` relies on module `B`, and class `C` relies on modules `A` and `B`. If I include `A` and `B` into `C`, this works, but I do not like the fact that `A` has a dependency on another module that must be mixed in along with it for it to work.

What is the "right" way to mix in modules in this situation? Should `A` mix in `B` itself? What if `C` also uses `B` directly?

```
module B
  def g
    12
  end
end

module A
  def f
    2 * g
  end
end

class C
  include A, B

  def h
    3 * f
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with writing `include` redundantly. If `A` and `C` both rely on `B`, then include `B` in both `A` and `C`.

```
module B
  def g; 12 end
  def i; 7 end
end

module A
  include B
  def f; 2 * g end
end

class C
  include A, B
  def h; 3 * f * i end
end
```

If `C` does no rely on `B`, then include `B` only in `A`.

```
module B
  def g; 12 end
end

module A
  include B
  def f; 2 * g end
end

class C
  include A
  def h; 3 * f end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `Module#included`

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include B
    end
  end
end
```

When this is done, B is included right after A.

Comment: This is a great solution, but be aware that load order determines while version of a method ends up on the object, if A and B both implement versions of the same method!

Comment: why not just `base.include B`?

Answer (score 0):

> Module A has a method that relies on functionality found in module B. [...]. What is the "right" way to mix in modules in this situation? Should A mix in B itself? What if C also uses B directly?

You've got few choice. Each of which should be chosen depending on the relationship between A, B and C.

The first one is to declare a module `D` that will define the shared functionality between `A` and `B`. In this way you can easily mix `D` with both `A` and `B` without worrying too much:

```
module D; ...; end
module A; include D; ...; end
module B; include D; ...; end
```

The other one that I can think of is to transform `A` and `B` into classes in order to use inheritance. Inheritance is good when having two classes that has a strong dependence relationship. If the functionality used by `A` is *strong enough* you should definitely choose this one:

```
class B; ...; end
class A < B; ...; end
class C < A; ...; end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? I can't seem to figure out `import` keyword that you use.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, sorry. I meant `include`. too much Python ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case, you have no overriding methods with the same names, whatever way you mix the mixins in, the instance methods will work together as intended. You just need to make sure that they are really mixed in:

```
[ A, B ].all? { |m| C.kind_of? m } # must be true
```

So, in your case, it does not matter whether you do this

```
class C; include A, B; end
```

or this

```
class C; include B, A; end
```

or this

```
module B; include A end
class C; include B end
```

or this

```
module A; include B end
class C; include A end
```

One caveat to remind you of is, that this will not work:

```
class C; include A; end # including the module A first
module A; include B end # and trying to remix it after
c = C.new               # does not work
c.h                     # raises NoMethodError
# Modules have to have finished mixing when they are included.
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong with just including B inside A if A depends on B and your modules only define instance methods. If you need class methods, you might want to consider http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

```
module B
  def method_b
    "B instance method"
  end
end

module A
  include B

  def method_a
    "A instance method is using #{method_b}"
  end
end

class Klass
  include A
end

k = Klass.new
puts k.method_a  #=> A instance method is using B instance method
puts k.method_b  #=> B instance method
puts k.class.ancestors.inspect  #=> [Klass, A, B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```